# SnowSQL - Getting permission denied error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm kinda new to SnowFlake. I've installed SnowSQL but when I'm trying to launch it's throwing the below error: I guess some issue in the config which I'm unable to figure out. Please advise!

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '%USERPROFILE%'
[27056] Failed to execute script bootstrap

Comment: Can you please  that you have access to the file %USERPROFILE%\.snowsql\ in the directory where it is sotred.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the configuration​ options log_file and log_bootstrap_file also point to the %userprofile% directory by default. Maybe set those to the network location too? You can do this by putting the options in the config file or using the -o flag when calling the CLI as described here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#snowsql-config-file